# Using JMeter to generate parts of message flows

Tags: java, http, web-applications, jmeter, load-testing

I am looking into whether I can use `JMeter` for load testing of a server.
I read that I can set it up as proxy to "record" a flow but I am not sure on the following.
Assume that I record a flow for 1 user which is like the following:

```
HTTP-1 req <data>    
HTTP-1 reply  
HTTP-2 req <data>    
HTTP-2 reply  
HTTP-3 req <data>    
HTTP-3 reply
```

Now in the `data` which is an `XML` fragment there is an item that is unique for each user e.g. `<user-id>AAA1</user-id>`
**Question:** Once the flow has been "recorded" and I want to simulate e.g. 50 concurrent users against my real server, is it possible each "user" to send the `data` with a *separate/different* `user-id`? E.g. for first *user* it will be `AAA1` as in the test case. For second *user* it will be `AAA2` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter can do this.

To send a different user-id:

- Use a [CSV Data Set config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), in it declare userId as a var , set sharing to all threads
- For each HTTP-N req , Use [HTTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) with Post Body mode, and use userId as a var : ${userId} in XML body

Depending on wether you use or not HTTP Session add a [Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

Comment: When you say `${userId}` in XML body you mean in the XML message the proxy has "recorded"?Also in the CSV I am supposed to write all the range of `userId`? E.g. `AAA1, AAA2, AAA3, ... AAA100`?

Comment: Yes in message change userid  value to variable and  yes csv will contain that

Comment: So for each "user/thread" and request it will use each of the `AAA1, AAA2 etc` in sequence so that each request will have a different XML msg in respect to `user-id`?